# Bigcommerce Custom js Module not working on Localhost

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I was developing an add-on for bigcommerce and i'm using cornerstone theme. Created custom template and mapped custom JavaScript module for it. However the case is, it's working fine on live store(Loading Data) when pushed. While it's not working on localhost. I searched and found only one thing related to it [here](https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/issues/1549). But it's not answered yet. So i was thinking if anyone has any work around for it. I'm using windows 10.

Comment: Hello there, I believe I tested this on a few OS and was only able to replicate on a non-WSL-enabled version of Windows 10. This doesn't occur when using macOS or an updated Linux-based OS.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I did installed distribution and Windows Subsystem for Linux. Following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10. Still doesn't work on local but works fine on live store. Also updated CLI. I'm not getting any errors as well.

Comment: Hi, If anyone is have this issue please install ubuntu WSL using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 and then installing cli on linux following Bigcommerce documentation.

Comment: You have to use WSL on Windows for this to work.